# How retrieve data from web service in Ajax Request (POST) blocked by web browser CORS policy

Tags: extjs, cors, wildfly-11

I want to make an Ajax request by POST method to a REST web service and get data from it, when use Postman the request works fine, but if i use a JavaScript framework like ExtJS 6 doesn't work, the web service are in java and is on a remote server. I get error by CORS policy on web browser. On the server WildFly 11 the CORS filters are configured.
How can i get the data from the service without blocked by CORS?

This is the request that i'm doing

```
...
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'url-to-my-web-service/method1',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            cors: true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            withCredentials: true,
            params : {
                "user": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "pwd": "xzxzxzxz"
            },
            success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                var result = conn.responseText;
                console.log("success...!");
            },
            failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                // TODO get the 'msg' from the json and display it
                console.log("error..!");
            }
        });
...
```

In WildFly 11 (standalone.xml)

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/11"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization,  content-type, x-requested-with"/>
            </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Java Code (ws class)

```
...
Interface interface = new ImpInterface();
    @OPTIONS
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/method1")
    public Response getToken(String clientData){
        return interface.method1(clientData);
    }
    }
...
```

Interface

```
public interface Interface  {
    public Response method1(String clientData);
}
```

Method1

```
public Response method1(String clientData) {
        ...
        try {
        ...
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject().put("test", objectTest).put("value", objectTest2).toString();

            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(jsonResponse)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
            return exception;
        }
}
```

The error in web browser console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url-to-my-web-service/method1' from origin 'null' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: 
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console? What is the HTTP status code of the response? (You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.)

Comment: I added the console message

Comment: So yeah as that error message indicates, the problem is that the server’s responding to OPTIONS request with a 400 Bad Request error. The server must be configured to instead respond to OPTIONS request with a 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

First : add `OPTIONS` handlers to your `Java Code (ws class)`.
Like this:

```
Interface interface = new ImpInterface();
    @OPTIONS
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/method1")
    public Response getToken(String clientData){
        return Response.status(201).entity("")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")
        .build();
    }
```

Next : `standalone.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/> 
                    <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/11"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization,  content-type, x-requested-with"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
                <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
            </filters>
</subsystem>
```

And in application you should add parameter like `withCredentials` with `true` value in your `Ext.Ajax.request`.

[withCredentials information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials):

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests.

Sencha [withCredentials documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-withCredentials):

> This configuration is sometimes necessary when using cross-origin resource sharing.

Example:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'url-to-my-web-service/method1',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            cors: true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            params : {
                "user": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
                "pwd": "xzxzxzxz"
            },
            success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                var result = conn.responseText;
                console.log("success...!");
            },
            failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                // TODO get the 'msg' from the json and display it
                console.log("error..!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I added the headers in java class and now get another error (updated the code and the error)

Comment: Now add  parameter  withCredentials to your `ajax request`.

Comment: The new error appears with that parameter on the request

Comment: Try to add `<filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
            <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>` after `<filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>` and add `<response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
        <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>` after `<response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>`

Comment: Look my edited answer - changed response and `standalone.xml`

Comment: Updated, the code is in a .war file and was developed with Jersey REST Service using javax ws, all of this on wildfly 11.